# Using PHPUnit, how do I mock a Doctrine Entity Repository class within a controller in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, mocking, phpunit

I am following the [guide](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/tutorials/unittesting.html#configuring-the-service-manager-for-the-tests) from Zend Framework 2's website on Unit Testing. My 'skeleton' app differs from the tutorial slightly in that I have integrated Doctrine 2 instead of using Zend's built in DB adapter.

Within the indexAction() of my AlbumController.php I am using the following snippet to retrieve all album records:

```
return new ViewModel(array(
        'albums' => $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('Album\Entity\Album')->findAll()    
));
```

How can I mock this in testIndexActionCanBeAccessed() within the IndexControllerTest.php file so that it returns dummy values?

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

create a mock of the EntityManager

create a mock of the AlbumRepository

create a mock of the AlbumEntity

then with PHP UNIT you would need to

```
create an $entityMock->expects($PHPUnit->once())->method('getRepository')->will($PHPUnit->returnValue($repositoryMock));

create a $repositoryMock->expects($PHPUnit->once())->method('findAll')->will($PHPUnit->returnValue(array($albumEntityMock));
```

depending on how you are implementing your PHPUnit testing the syntax may differ, but the steps should help you along the way.